# C++20 chrono, parsing into zoned time and formatting without trailing decimals

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono

I am writing a bit of code that intakes a string from a user, and formats it into a zoned time. The parsing code is a bit more complicated than this example, but this will reproduce problem.

This is compiled with MSVC++ compiled with /std:c++latest.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::string timeString("2020-02-03 00:12:34");
    std::string formatString("%Y-%m-%d %T");

    bool successful = true;
    std::stringstream iss(timeString);
    std::chrono::local_time<std::chrono::system_clock::duration> localTimeStamp;
    if (not (iss >> std::chrono::parse(formatString, localTimeStamp))) {
        successful = false;
    }
    auto result = std::chrono::zoned_time(std::chrono::current_zone(), localTimeStamp);

    std::cout << std::format("{:%Y-%m-%d %T}", result) << std::endl;
}
```

Results in the following output:

`2020-02-03 00:12:34.0000000`

I would like for the output to not have the trailing decimals. Since it's a string, I can always truncate the string at the decimal anyway. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't have MSVC to test, but try to shove a `.0` in there somewhere Maybe something like this `"{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:.0%S}"`

Comment: This only adds a ".0" in front of the seconds position. The example above becomes `2020-02-03 00:12:.034.0000000`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the type of `localTimeStamp` to have `seconds` precision:

```
std::chrono::local_time<std::chrono::seconds> localTimeStamp;
```

There's also this convenience type-alias to do the same thing if you prefer:

```
std::chrono::local_seconds localTimeStamp;
```

The precision of the parsing and formatting is dictated by the precision of the `time_point` being used.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I ended up converting between the two clocks using

 `std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::seconds, std::chrono::local_t> (localTimeStamp);`

It's a bit wordy, but I'll shove it into a function, so it works!